# JavaScript make value of variable public

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope

Here is excerpt from my larger JavaScript file:

```
function dashboardConfig()
{
    $(window).on('resize', function () {

        var viewport = {
            width : $(this).width(),
            height : $(this).height()
        };

        el.siteContainer.css(
        {
            marginTop : (viewport.height - 652) / 2
        });

        el.dashboardSlide.css(
        {
            marginLeft : (viewport.width - 1024) / 2,
            marginRight : (viewport.width - 1024) / 2
        });

        //Calculate how many nav elements
        el.navElements.each(function(i)
        {           
            el.dashboard.css(
            {
                width : viewport.width * (i + 1)
            });

            $(this).click(function()
            {
                //HERE IS THE VARIABLE I WOULD LIKE TO USE
                var dashboardSlidePosition = viewport.width * i;

                el.navElements.removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');

                el.dashboard.animate(
                {
                    left : -dashboardSlidePosition
                },500, function()
                {
                    el.dashboard.css(
                    {
                        left : -dashboardSlidePosition
                    });
                });
            });
        });

        //I WANT TO PERFORM ANOTHER FUNCTION HERE AND HAVE IT USE THE VALUE OF dashboardSlidePosition


    }).trigger('resize');
}
```

I want to know how I can pass the value of the variable, dashboardSlidePosition, to another function. Please can anyone explain how?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Declare it in a higher scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare it at the outer edge of your scope.  Make sure to give it an initial value so that you don't try to use it before it has been set properly.

```
function dashboardConfig()
{
    var dashboardSlidePosition = null;

    function anotherFunction() {
        if (dashboardSlidePosition != null) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    $(this).click(function()
    {
        dashboardSlidePosition = viewport.width * i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put it into the proper scope:

```
function dashboardConfig()
{
    var dashboardSlidePosition = 0;
```

Next, remove `var` when redefining it.

Now you can use it because it's in the scope of the function.